# abstract class and polymorphism

Tags: c++, polymorphism, clone, virtual

I am working on something with abstract class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Shape
{
protected:
    int m_size;
public:
    int getSize() { return m_size; }

    virtual bool isEqual(Shape *rhs) = 0;
};
```

Here is one of the derived class:

```
class Circle : public Shape
{
public:
    Circle(int size) { m_size = size; }

    bool isEqual(Shape *rhs)
    {
        Circle* circle = dynamic_cast<Circle*>(rhs);

        if(circle == 0)
            return false; // not a Circle

        return m_size == circle->getSize();
    }
};
```

And I store all shapes in a container (basically a vector of pointer of shape.

```
class Container
{
private:
    vector<Shape*> v;
public:   
    ~Container()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
            cout << "Removind element Nr. " << i << endl;
            delete v[i];
        }
        v.erase(v.begin(), v.end());
    }

    bool add(Shape *shape) 
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {

            if( v[i] == shape ) { 
                return false;
            }

            if( v[i]->isEqual(shape) ) {
                return false;
            }

        }
        v.push_back(shape);
        return true;
    }

};
```

I would like to know if it is possible to add element in the container without passing them as pointer.
Currently it works like that:

```
Container c;
c.add(new Circle(10));
```

And I would like to use it in this way:

```
C.add(Circle(10));
```

What would be the solution?

Comment: BTW, virtual destructor is missing.

Comment: Is virtual destructor needed?

Comment: @bandara: It is nearly free to add it, and it avoids memleak (once you have a destructor in a child class)...

Answer (score 5):

Don't store polymorphic objects by value. This may result in [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

In your case it is not even possibly to store objects of type `Shape` by value because the class has pure virtual methods.

If you want better resource management, e.g. automatically calling `delete`, you can use `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`.

.

Comment: But the question does not suggest storing by value, only passing to `add` by value.

Answer (score 0):

You can not if you want to use the container uniformly and save any type of Shape (circle,rectangle ..) in the same container. For example, currently you can add any shape by using the base class pointer. But if you want to add object, not pointer, you have to declare one container for each type. You will not be able to handle the objects uniformly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move creation of the new object to the `Container::add` so the object is created only if it is not in the container. One way to achieve it is to declare the pure virtual `Clone` function in `Shape` and then define it in `Circle`:

```
virtual Shape* Clone()
{
    return new Circle(*this);
}
```

Then you can pass the object by value to `add`, and it will call `Clone`:

```
v.push_back(shape.Clone());
```

Comment: This will still call `new`, involves an additional call to the copy constructor, and you need a method `Clone` for every derived class. What would be the benefit?

Comment: The benefit is that is solves the problem of having a container of pointers to polymorphic objects and adding an object only if it is not already in the container. Do you have any other ideas how it can be solved? Note that my solution can be easily extended to use smart pointers and avoid manual deleting in the container destructor.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the clone method,
You can modify your method `add` by something like (in C++11):

```
template<typename T, typename...Ts>
bool Container::add(Ts&&... args)
{
    std::unique_ptr<T> newShape(new T(std::forward<Ts>(args)...));
    for (const Shape* shape : v) {
        const auto* shapeT = dynamyc_cast<const T*>(shape);

        if (shapeT != nullptr && shapeT->isEqual(newShape) ) {
            return false;
        }

    }
    v.push_back(newShape.release()); // better to have std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Shape>>...
    return true;
}
```

And then use it like:

```
c.add<Circle>(10);
```